# Angular: Is it possible to do an action when someone selects an option?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Angular and I have to use it with Bootstrap. I have to do a conditional form. In my form I have an input text field and an input select with 3 options. So when the user selects one option, I have to display some data which are different if the user selects the first, second or third option. In jquery I would retrieve the ID of the option selected and append an html on the existing DOM.

I think with Angular it is different. I don't know really how to do. Is there a directive to use if I want to call an action when user changes the option of input select?

Could someone explain it to me or give me sample code?

Comment: You need to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with some show/hides if you are talking about displaying html instead of just a message.  The `$watch` on the controller can fire and change data as well as the value (selected) changes.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model='selected' ng-options='option for option in options'></select>

    <div ng-show='selected=="one"'>
      One
    </div>
     <div ng-show='selected=="two"'>
      Two
    </div>
  </body>
```

Controller:

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.options = ['one','two'];

  $scope.$watch('option', function(val) {
    // this runs when it is changed if you want to do something with the value

  });

});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NA3akxXBQGX0dHqYH0UJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-change="doSomething(selection)">
   <option value="selection1">Selection 1</option>
   <option value="selection2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
<div ng-show="showMessage">{{showMessage}}</div>


$scope.doSomething = function(selection){
   // do what you want to do or create your message
   if(selection=='selection1')
       $scope.showMessage = "You select first";
   else if(selection == 'selection2')
       $scope.showMessage = "You select second";

}
```